# How to Register Salesforce Marketing Cloud Developer Account?

Tags: marketing-cloud, developer-edition

I want to go through the exacttarget and want to learn it features, Can anybody help me on creating exacttarget developer org.

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: looks like a developer org marketing cloud is not available for registration at this time: https://code.exacttarget.com/developer-edition/

Answer (score 3):

Marketing Cloud Developer Edition accounts were announced at Connections 2014 and were available for a limited period after the event. If you signed up for one at this time, it will work, but you can't register for new accounts at this time. I also asked the question and the "official" response that I received was:

> We have removed the auto-provision signup for the Developer Edition. We
>   intermittently host the signup form online to support the Developer Zone
>   experience at respective Salesforce Events (Dreamforce, SF1 World Tour,
>   etc). The features enabled in Developer Edition support very specific
>   use-cases needed for those events.
>
> We have received excellent feedback from the developer community
>   regarding the enablement of additional features not currently offered in
>   the Developer Edition accounts. We are exploring options for a formal
>   Developer Edition product launch later this year that will include
>   greater feature options for users.

I'd love to see a formal developer program launched like Salesforce offer for [force.com](https://developer.salesforce.com/signup?d=70130000000EjH). In the meantime, the only option is to purchase a Sandbox Account.